# Lightbox with multiple images not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, lightbox

I'm trying to use standard lightbox. Everything was working perfect until I tried to add multiple images to one 'set'.

Just using standard syntax with no mods

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
<link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<a href="images/famroom.jpg" rel="lightbox[rooms]" title="Family Room"><img src="images/famroom.jpg" alt="Bedroom" width="250" height="188" class="fltrt"></a>Accommodation</h4>    
<a href="images/twinroom.jpg" rel="lightbox[rooms]" title="Twin Room"></a>
<a href="images/doubleroom.jpg" rel="lightbox[rooms]" title="Double Room"></a>
<a href="images/bathroom.jpg" rel="lightbox[rooms]" title="Bathroom"></a>
```

The above doesn't work. It shows up as a broken image, when I click I just see a pure white image.

However this (for example) works fine.

```
<a href="images/famroom.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="Family Room"><img src="images/famroom.jpg" alt="Wedding Table" width="250" height="188" class="fltlft"></a>
```

Its only IE8 I'm having this problem (haven't tried 6, 7 or 9), it works perfect in FF and Chrome. No other scripts are in use on the page.

Comment: Are you planning on actually having more then 1 set? If not there's no reason to put it in a set.

Comment: I have other lightboxes on the page with single images. I just want this first lightbox to have one image on the page and once clicked it will show the arrows to navigate the three other images. As far as I can make out, I need to use sets for this?

Comment: Yes you do... I'm not sure why it would work in FF and Chrome but not IE. Did you assign all the sets a specific name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a strange resolution to this one. It turns out this just didn't work locally.

When I uploaded it to the server it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested on IE8 and my example seems to be working, perhaps compare to my example and see if you  have maybe missed something?

http://jsfiddle.net/n1ck/RcA3a/3/

I am including (taken from their demo page):

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/css/lightbox.css"   type="text/css" media="screen">
 <script src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/js/lightbox.js"></script>
```